# Why does the Element Hiding Helper for Adblock Plus recommends against binding a rule to every domain?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, adblock

I'm running Firefox with Adblock Plus and [Element Hiding Helper](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/elemhidehelper/) on a Windows 8 laptop.

I use Element Hiding Helper to hide all sorts of annoyances and distractions, including the "You Might Also Like" boxes found on some websites.

When I select an element and tell the Helper to hide it, it opens up a dialog box.  This lets me can choose which domain(s) the rule will apply to.

Now, the Helper allows me to bind the rule to a specific domain.  Or it lets me specify that the rule will apply to `any domain (not recommended)`.  See screenshot.

I would like to bind each of my element hiding rules (such as `##.gp-might-like` and `##.sidebar`) to every domain.  Why does the Helper tell me that it's "not recommended" to bind a rule to every domain?

[image: Screenshot of Element Hiding Helper's "Compose element hiding rule" dialog box]

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason: Adblock Plus comes with a *whitelist* of acceptable sites, and has agreements , https://adblockplus.org/en/acceptable-ads, with some advertisers, which a universal rule might block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a rule for a generic ID (like `#main`) or class name (like your own example, `.sidebar`) would break millions of sites.  It is very common to have relevant content on a sidebar, like the "How to Edit" and "How to Format" sections that appear when you create a page on this very website (Super User).

They don't want users who don't know what they are doing to do that and then complain on their forums that many sites stopped working properly.